# Get CityName from Geobytes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this code to get information about my ip address

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity,GeobytesRegion,GeobytesLatitude,GeobytesLongitude");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Label1.Text = responseFromServer.ToString();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

It returns to `label1`

```
var sGeobytesLocationCode="PKPBRAWA";
var sGeobytesIsLocationMatch=false;
var sGeobytesCountry="Pakistan";
var sGeobytesRegion="Punjab";
var sGeobytesCity="Rawalpindi";
var sGeobytesLatitude="33.6000";
var sGeobytesLongitude="73.0670";
```

How do I get only the city name from this. As in my case Rawalpindi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string temp = responseFromServer.ToString();

Match _matchdec = Regex.Match(temp, @"\ssGeobytesCity=""\b(\S*)\b""", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (_matchdec.Success)
{
   string retval = _matchdec.Groups[1].Value;   
   Label1.Text = retval ;  
}
```

Add namespace `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Hope this help.